Why do I get a value error while creating a ragged array but only for a certain shape?
import numpy as np

for h in range(10):
    try:
        array = np.array([np.zeros((h, 4)), np.zeros((3, h))], dtype=object)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Value Error for h={h} only.')

In the above code, ValueError only happens for h=3. This seems arbitrary.
The full error being,
  File "path/to/arr.py", line 4, in <module>
    array = np.array([np.zeros((h, 4)), np.zeros((3, h))], dtype=object)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,4) into shape (3,)

How may I avoid this and why does this happen?


When you create an array of arrays in numpy, it tries to combine them into a regular, multi-dimensional array if possible.
At h=3 both the arrays happen to have same no.of rows.

first array : (3,4)
second array : (3,3)


So numpy thinks u might want to stack these arrays, but their column sizes 4 & 3 don't match, resulting in ValueError.
For other values of h, the no.of rows in the array are different, so it doesn't attempt to stack them.
We need to explicitly pass each array as separate object by creating an empty object array & assigning the arrays individually, so numpy won't combine the arrays.

import numpy as np

for h in range(10):
    array = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
    array[0] = np.zeros((h, 4))
    array[1] = np.zeros((3, h))

